# GNU make error code (e = -1)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a strange problem. I have been previously using GNU make for the last 4 weeks with no issues. I'm pointing my make file to an avr toolchain to cross compile for an ATMEL processor. A few days ago, GNU make stopped working. When I run `make` I get the following output:

```
    make (e=-1): Error -1
    make: *** [main.o] Error -1
```

To try and get more insight to the problem, I ran the code with just the echo output using `make -n`. It prints all of the statements in the makefile, including the commands. A short snippet of this output is as follows:

```
    echo
    echo "=================================="
    echo "Compiling: " main.c
    echo "=================================="
    "/c/Users/Shane Reynolds/Documents/CDU_embeddedSystems/CDUEmbeddedToolbox/avr_tools/bin/avr-gcc" -c -std=gnu99 -g -mmcu=atmega1281 -DF_CPU=16000000UL -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os main.c -o main.o
```

You can see that the command is printed at the end of this short snippet of the output. If I copy and paste the command into the terminal then the process works fine - but doing this every time is annoying. To try and understand why GNU make was failing I ran the debug tag `make -d` and received a lot of output. The snippet of what I think is important is:

```
    CreateProcess(C:\Users\Shane Reynolds\Documents\CDU_embeddedSystems\CDUEmbeddedToolbox\avr_tools\utils\bin\echo.exe,echo,...)
    Putting child 0x0043fdf0 (main.o) PID 4486808 on the chain.
    Live child 0x0043fdf0 (main.o) PID 4486808
    Main thread handle = 0x000000a8

    Reaping winning child 0x0043fdf0 PID 4486808
    Live child 0x0043fdf0 (main.o) PID 4488168
    Reaping losing child 0x0043fdf0 PID 4488168
    make (e=-1): Error -1
    make: *** [main.o] Error -1
    Removing child 0x0043fdf0 PID 4488168 from chain.
```

Can anyone help me with this? I've spent a couple of days trying to figure this out. I really hope that it is not something glaringly obvious, or simple.

EDIT: to add a little bit more background, I am using this on Windows 8 - when I run `make` from either bash or cmd I get the same error message. The link to my makefile is:

https://pastebin.com/j7uMSLic

FURTHER EDIT: I've created a very simple makefile with a very simple source code - running this produces the same error, but I can use the AVR toolchain to compile and link manually just like the previous case.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it isn't a compile error in your code? I know it's pretty obvious, but sometimes our eyes are drawn to the wrong place...

Comment: I'm using the AVR tool chain to compile. Running the code which uses the `avr-gcc` command works fine - I can manually create the `.o`, `.elf`, and `.hex`. I have no problems loading the program to the target processor either. From my understanding make is just a script which points to the various tools that you want to use for compiling.

Comment: Are you using `-j`? If parallel builds are happening, make's output can be confusing ...

Comment: Yes. The `-j` tag is used. It is used solely in a line in the makefile. I commented this out and ran the makefile using the following code instead `$(OBJCOPY) -R .eeprom -O ihex $< $@`, however, the same output was received.

Comment: Does rolling back to a previous working commit still have the same error? Is your toolchain under source control?

Comment: The toolchain is under source control, however, there have been no edits to these files. The toolchain still works if I call them them using manually entered commands (or if I copy and paste the commands which are ouput from running `make -n`). Further to this, I tried rolling back to earlier makefile and source code `main.c` which I know have worked previously. The error persists in both of these cases.

Comment: I feel like I'm closing in on a solution - could it be something to do with the path that GNU make uses? I updated Anaconda the a few days ago, and this has made changes to the windows PATH system variable. Does anyone know if this could be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.

So it turns out that it was something to do with Git bash (the terminal that I was using). Somewhere, somehow, I think one of the path variables got messed up. I completely uninstalled Git, and then re-installed and it works fine now. Not sure how this happened, but am glad to have it fixed.

If anyone else has an explanation, or can add more insight to the problem and how it can be avoided then feel free to post below.